# Pass arguments to graphviz for pydot graph

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I've got a pydot graph representing a hierarchy I've generated in `networkx` and I'm trying to output it to disk with `graphviz` attributes.

So far I've got:

```
p = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(G)
p.write_png('test.png')
```

This is fine, but the graph can get pretty cluttered and super wide with a bunch of nodes at the same level in the hierarchy, so I'd love to play with some `graphviz` attributes like `nodesep` and `ranksep`. I've been trying to read through the `networkx` documentation online, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how/where to feed the attributes in.

Comment: You can save it in  **dot** output format (not png) and then tweak + feed to Graphviz until you are satisfied.